# Communicating between two picker views in my view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

In my project there are two category(**audio/tv**) in picker1. When user click on row of audio the below list in picker2 should change to (**audio1,audio2,audio3**) and if tv is selected in picker1 then in picker2 shoulc change to (**tv1,tv2,tv3**).

What should i write in following function?

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if ([[devicecatogery objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"Audio"]) {
        NSLog(@"Audio is selected");
     }else if ([[devicecatogery objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"TV"]){
       NSLog(@"TV is selected");
    }    
    NSLog(@"selected row:%d , component:%d" , row,component);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the second picker values array. This is the array that you use in the following method:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

After you have changed values array you must reload second picker components this way:

```
[secondPicker reloadAllComponents] /*or [secondPicker reloadComponent:0] if you have only one component*/
```

Answer (score 0):

When u change picker1 you can use `[picker2 selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:NO];` to change picker2,and set the value u want.